# SQL Server - need to return LIKE matches for entries in specific columns of a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, sql-like

Got a bit of a tricky one here folks. Have had a search round and can't find anything quite like this I'm afraid.

I need to set up a query that will return all like matches grouped by matching criterion in the following scenario:

Account_name entry in one row is LIKE account_name entry in one or more other row(s)

*AND/OR* account_number entry in one row EQUALS account_number entry in one or more other row(s)

*WHEN*
Open_date of most recent entry is within 90 calendar days of Close_date of other entry(s)

Further refinement would be to specify a time period (usually a calendar month, possibly a quarter) in which the most recent by open_date falls.

Everything required is within one table, no primary key is currently defined but the main idenifier is a unique ref different to `account_number`. Due to shared use of table, may not be able to make amendments such as defining primary key.

Example, want to search for repeat orders (ideally within specified time period, a calendar month, a quarter) where a customer has initiated new order after having closed another order within a specified time period (90 days.)  When results spit out, need them to group so that the "repeat/duplicate orders are grouped together and data in all colums for each entry is returned.

Like is required on customer_name because legacy and ongoing issues lead to duplicate customer entries being set up where an account_number doesn't exist.

Thanks in advance folks, from a logic point of view, I can't see any problems defining the criteria, but as a SQL n00b, I'm struggling where to star even writing the query.

EDIT sample data and desired result below:

```
Order_Ref   Account_Name    Account_Number  Open_date   Close_date  other_thing_1   other_thing_2   other_thing_3

1   John Smith  1001    1st Jan 2017    1st Feb 2017    xx  xx  xx

2   Jim Brown   1002    1st Feb 2017    15th Feb 2017   xx  xx  xx

3   Emily Flathead  1003    1st Mar 2017    15th Mar 2017   xx  xx  xx

4   Joane Sandhu    1004    1st Apr 2017    14th Apr 2017   xx  xx  xx

5   John Smith  1001    15th Aug 2017   30th Aug 2017   xx  xx  xx

6   Reuben Goldman  1005    1st Sept 2017   10th Sept 2017  xx  xx  xx

7   John Smithh 1006    5th Sept 2017   19th Sept 2017  xx  xx  xx

8   Sandra Jackson  1007    10th Sept 2017  19th Sept 2017  xx  xx  xx

9   Peter Jenkins   1008    19th Sept 2017  3rd Oct 2017    xx  xx  xx

10  John Smith  1001    1st Oct 2017    12th Oct 2017   xx  xx  xx

11  Emily Flathead  1003    3rd Oct 2017    14th Oct 2017   xx  xx  xx

12  Emily Flathead  1003    20th Oct 2017   NULL    xx  xx  xx
```

Desired result

```
5   John Smith  1001    15th Aug 2017   30th Aug 2017   xx  xx  xx

7   John Smithh 1006    5th Sept 2017   19th Sept 2017  xx  xx  xx

10  John Smith  1001    1st Oct 2017    12th Oct 2017   xx  xx  xx

11  Emily Flathead  1003    3rd Oct 2017    14th Oct 2017   xx  xx  xx

12  Emily Flathead  1003    20th Oct 2017   NULL    xx  xx  xx
```

Idea is to highlight the recent John Smith and John Smithh orders but ignore the historic one and also recent Emily Flathead orders but ignore historic one.

Actual dates are in datetime and NULL is allowed (for close_date) written longhand to avoid confusion as I/m UK based.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help explain what you want to do.

Comment: No problem, here's an anonymised set:

Comment: Dammit, I'm over character limit.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute "Table" with your table name.

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM Table A
WHERE A.Open_date = (SELECT MAX(B.Open_date) 
                     FROM Table B
                     WHERE (B.Account_name = A.Account_name
                     OR B.Account_number = A.Account_number)
                     AND (A.Open_date <= DATEADD('day', 90, B.Close_date)
                     OR B.Close_date IS NULL))
AND (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table B
              WHERE B.Account_name = A.Account_name
              AND A.Open_date > B.Open_date
              AND (A.Open_date <= DATEADD('day', 90, B.Close_date)
                   OR B.Close_date IS NULL)
OR EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table B
           WHERE B.Account_number = A.Account_number
           AND A.Open_date > B.Open_date
           AND (A.Open_date <= DATEADD('day', 90, B.Close_date)
                OR B.Close_date IS NULL))
```

Comment: I don't believe this will satisfy the requirement of:  "Open_date of most recent entry is within 90 calendar days of Close_date of other entry(s)".   This looks for any related entry within 90 days, and not only the most recent.

Comment: It would leave out the oldest record though. Edited to make sure we get the latest.

Comment: Am I getting closer yet?